# Using '@val3' or @val3 in SQL Server query parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, sql-server-2012

I am just wondering what is the correct way for sending this old query statement:

```
"SELECT " +
   "* " +
"FROM " +
   "tE " +
"WHERE " +
   "active = 1 " +
"AND " +
   "StartDate = " + Session["between"] + " " +
"AND " +
   "UPPER(I1) = '" + Session["StrUser"].ToString().ToUpper() + "'"
```

To this way (correct way of passing the parameters):

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet _ds1 = new DataSet();

String blah = "SELECT " +
                 "* " +
              "FROM " +
                 "tE " +
              "WHERE " +
                 "active = @val1 " +
              "AND " +
                 "StartDate @val2 " +
              "AND " +
                 "UPPER(I1) = '@val3'"

command = new SqlCommand(blah, con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", 1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", Session["between"].ToString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", Session["StrUser"].ToString().ToUpper());

da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(_ds1, dbName);
da.Dispose();

closeAllConnections();
command.Parameters.Clear();

return _ds1;
```

The main focus of this question is the `'@val3'"` part. Is that needed or will the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` automatically place that if needed?

Comment: `"StartDate @val2 " ` misses a `=` and `"UPPER(I1) = '@val3'"` has two invalid `'`

Comment: Thanks @fubo .... must have missed that when typing it. Corrected.

Comment: @fubo the **'@val3'** is the question at hand...

Comment: If you're going to use `AddWithValue`, [be aware of its potential pitfalls](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Also, are you sure there should be a `=` after `StartDate` - the fact that the parameter is called "between" is making me wonder if it should be generating something like `StartDate between x and y`, in which case you'll need to use two parameters to replace that part of the query, rather than injecting the full between parameter it's currently doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using parameters is a good way of separating SQL *code* from *data*. As such, you should understand that the `'` characters are part of a *data* literal. As such, unless you're wanting to compare `I1` with the literal string `@val3`, and instead want to use the *parameter*, it should not be enclosed in `'`s.

This is correct:

```
String blah = "SELECT " +
             "* " +
          "FROM " +
             "tE " +
          "WHERE " +
             "active = @val1 " +
          "AND " +
             "StartDate = @val2 " +
          "AND " +
             "UPPER(I1) = @val3"
```

> will the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` automatically place that if needed?

No, it will not - because you're no longer trying to construct a *literal* value, no `'`s are required *at all*. Parameters *aren't* just a fancy way of doing text replacement - they keep the code and data separate and, importantly, deal with any required *conversions* behind the scenes.

Comment: ..More importantly parameters are used to prevent sql injection :)

Comment: @StealthRT - they do. And the *means* by which they prevent injection is separating code from data - so that there's no possibility that part of the data will be *misinterpreted* as being code.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge!